# Excel data connection to system tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel

I'm trying to connect to system tables in MSDB

```
[msdb].[sysjobs], [msdb].[sysjobhistory]
```

from Excel, but the these tables wouldn't be displayed in the Data Connection Wizard in Excel.

Can you please advise if this not possible at all or I'm not connecting it the right way ?

Answer (score 0):

I just connected to my excel and connected using my credentials which is SA and I did not see those views or system tables. I created a view

Create view dbo.alljobs as
Select * from dbo.sysjobs_view

And now the view dbo.alljobs appears in Excel.